# Why do we need to use element when we have already stated class?

Tags: html, css, class, element

In css, if a person has already stated a class then why does he need to use element after that like what will be the benefits of doing that. For example:
There is a class of "content" in element 
So what will be the difference in css between:
.content h1 {...}
And 
.content {....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.content h1` represents any `h1` tag to any level of child component inside all the elements having class as `content` whereas `.content` refers to the elements having class as `content`.